# I got error in PHP preg_match. content constains [^>]*?

Tags: php, regex

Nearly, when i write code with preg_match.Like this

```
    $string = <<<ETO
    <svg "[^>]*? width="480.24px" height="360px" viewBox="0 0 480.24 360" enable-background="new 0 0 480.24 360" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    ETO;

    preg_match('/<svg[^>]*?width=[\'|"]{1}(.*?)[\'|"]{1}[^>]*?>/is', $string, $svginfo);
```

the `$svginfo` got null.

Sorry about this. I know `[^>]*?` should not be there in svg.
But when someone posts this I need to get the width info from this content.

Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: i suspect you need to add some escaping

Comment: [^>]*? in $string. it's just a accident

Comment: I have to delete the `[^>]*?` from `$string` to get a match - if you don't mean it to be there, please edit the question.

Comment: show us the real question or dont bother

Comment: remove [^>]*? from $string will be matched ok.  It's just a example.AND FOR MORE. when users post some content like this,and you need to do some preg on content.How do this ?

Comment: Please do not edit crucial bits of the question - you've changed the regex (but not the `$string` corruption), yet in my answer I showed you how to fix the original regex, and the second match would be the width you were searching for.

Comment: Sorry, i just want to explain problem more detailed. I know how to get the width info.What i care is Why $string contains [^>]*? will be error

Answer (score 0):

Testing out on an [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/Bydy1g/1), it tells me:

```
\\ matches the character \ literally (case insensitive)
1 matches the character 1 literally (case insensitive)
```

If instead I use `\1` in the middle of the string, it says:

```
\1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
```

This means that you will find the matching closing quote, which is what you seem to want to do.

Oh, and [Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1270789).

---

**UPDATE:**

Ah, this *is* the Zalgo problem. The problem is that you want to ensure you don't skip over the whole `<svg .... >` tag, so that `<svg>width="99"` is rejected. A simple and valid HTML pattern would be:

```
<svg name=">" width="42">
```

A regex to catch this and similar variants will soon get out of hand; the proper way to do this is use an HTML parser; here is [one article about how to do it](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html).

Comment: I got this error.because,In preg_match, i use " as the delimiter, so i write \\1. when i use single quote   \1 is ok

Comment: Maybe u can use this <svg[^>]*?width=['|"]{1}(.*?)['|"]{1}[^>]*?> again

Comment: Sorry i am chinese with poor English. Please forgive me

Comment: Yes, [that alternative version works](https://regex101.com/r/Bydy1g/2), although it will also match mismatched quotes, eg `width="480.24px'` will be accepted.

Comment: ok, i'll update. I had updated this problem. The main problem is Why can't match info when $string contains [^>]*?

Comment: Cool! i got it. Thank u